# Convert a GeoJSON polygon to a Cesium.Plane object

Tags: geojson, cesium, plane

I have a polygon (planar) in a [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/) feature.

I would like to convert it to a true [Cesium.Plane](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/Plane.html) object.

How could I achieve that?

In my current code, the feature is only a [dataSource](https://cesium.com/docs/cesiumjs-ref-doc/DataSource.html) object:

```
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

const GeoJSON = {
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "name":"MyPolygon",
    "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},
    "features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":
      [[[10.746500,48.31470,500],
        [10.747500,48.31570,500],
        [10.747038,48.31590,550],
        [10.746038,48.31490,550],
        [10.746500,48.31470,500]]]}}]
};

const loadData = async () => {
    try {
        const dataSource = await Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load(GeoJSON, {
                stroke: Cesium.Color.BLUE,
                fill: new Cesium.Color(0.2, 0.2, 1, 0.2),
                strokeWidth: 3
        });
        viewer.dataSources.add(dataSource);
        viewer.zoomTo(dataSource);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
    }
};
loadData();
```

https://sandcastle.cesium.com/